Select single value fom slicer based on other slicer
Hi I am trying to Sync values from slicer based on other slice which have relation StartDT to StartDt_1 and EndDt to EndDt_1 (both have onetoone and Cross-filter "both")
Here i StartDt_1 and EndDt_1 has bined to SQL query parameter's
The reason i am doing to sync is StartDt_1 and EndDt_1 which are bined is i can not convert them as date's as i am passing them as string in power query
Now , if select any date form StartDt it should reflect on Start_1 and same fpr EndDt's
Below is the query
filterquery = "SELECT * FROM Schema1.TabName where ""date"" >= '" & DateTime.ToText(StartDate,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' And ""date"" <= '" & DateTime.ToText(Date.AddDays( Enddate,1),"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"


Thanks in advance.
